# Nginx as a reverse proxy doesn't resolve

Tags: nginx, reverse-proxy

I'm trying to use NGINX as a simple reverse proxy. My content is live on localhost:7700.

These are my steps:

```
apt-get -qq install nginx -y
rm -f /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/default
cat << EOF > /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/meilisearch
server {
    listen 80 default_server;
    listen [::]:80 default_server;
    server_name _;
    location / {
        proxy_pass  http://localhost:7700;
    }
}
EOF

systemctl daemon-reload
systemctl enable nginx
systemctl restart nginx
```

Apparently Ngninx is running ok when I look at:

service nginx status

However when I go to my IP of my server I don't see the content, it just says "Failed to open page". Where am I going wrong? There is nothing in the access.log or error.log of nginx.

Comment: why did you delete the default configuration which already have the need part?